# Explanation and Draw of Line Impedance Stabilization Network (LISN)

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, passive-networks, linear-regulator, fourier

[image: Succesfull Example Hopefully]I am trying to learn about LISN circuits. As far as I see, there are standards for LISN. But the point is everybody is applying standards, I would like to know why these values are chosen or why there are these capacitors and indictors. If it is a low pass filter, why there are more components? Is it about fourier transformation? and Which calculations exactly. I would appreciate if someone explain these but I am fine to read all from a source (couldn't find good source yet, that's why I am asking here)+ I dont want to waste you guys time as well. Thanks a lot for your all answers. I will add an example circuit here if someone wants to explain on picture.
[image: Example Basic LISN Circuit]

Comment: I think you should look for a LISN with all the values specified if you want a proper answer.

Comment: Hi, there are many LISN circuits with exact values, I just didnt want to put them here and make content longer, it is long already, but I will add it now then. Thank you!

Comment: Your new top circuit isn't a LISN as far as I can tell.

Comment: Hope it is a LISN this time. Btw it is my bad, I found out when I was looking for, it was one with so many different things added

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know why these values are chosen

The exact values are somewhat arbitrary, but a) they are meant to be standard, so that tests are repeatable and b) they are meant to "swamp" the inductances and capacitances that are present on a "mains" line, which vary.

> or why there are these capacitors and indictors. If it is a low pass filter, why there are more components?

The purpose of a LISN is not simply a low pass filter. The purpose is to a) provide a relatively known line impedance to the device under test, and b) to *redirect* high frequency signals from the device under test to the EMI receiver, rather than to *attenuate* those signals.

> Is it about fourier transformation?

The EMI receiver could be a spectrum analyser, and perform Fourier Transformations, but what the EMI receiver does with the signal it receives is not something the LISN is concerned about.

Comment: I see, actually just like you said, its main purpose is giving a stable impedance, but I am really curious how it works for this case. what is going on there and giving a fixed value for impedance. I am sorry again, maybe it sounds so beginner but I really couldn't find an exact document which explains these all.

Comment: When I say that the circuit "swamps" the values of inductance and capacitance of the mains line, what I mean is that the values of the components in the LISN are significantly greater than those in the mains line. So, even if the values in the mains line change, that change won't affect the _total_ by a large percentage.

Comment: I got it a bit, thanks for explanation. But I would like to ask one more, why there are C1, C2, L1, R1 and R2. I mean their real purpose in this circuit. Now I get values of them a bit more but need to know reason of their existence in this circuit too